# Zend framework 2 : not able to send desired status code in response

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-rest

I am building REST API on Zend Framework 2. I want to send certain status code in response whenever any error has occurred.

I tried below in my controller :

```
$statusCode = 401;
$this->response->setStatusCode($statusCode);
return new JsonModel(array("error message" => "error description"));
```

Echoing status code prints `401`, but client-side application gets status code `200` every time.

How can I set status code to particular value?

**Module.php :**

```
class Module 
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
                     'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                                                               __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
                                                               ),
                     'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                                                               'namespaces' => array(
                                                                                     __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                                                                                     ),
                                                               ),
                     );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

}
```

**EDIT :** Below is how the response looks :
[image]

Comment: This code works for me.

Comment: @akond I still get 200 as status code. Please see the edit.

Comment: I get `HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: I advice checking your web-server setup. There might be some redirection configured or http-code is forced. Also, have you tried using other status codes?

Comment: And try using $this->getResponse() instead of $this->response.

Comment: @Xardas I have not set up any redirection. I am not aware of any already set redirection(by framework) though. I tried `getResponse()`, too.

Comment: Could you post full code of your controller? What class does your controller extend?

Comment: @Xardas I am simply placing 3 lines of code(which is posted in question) in my controller. I have created an abstract controller `myController`, which extends `AbstractRestfulController`. All controllers then extend `myController`.

Comment: @Geek Is it possible, that there is output start somewhere before your controller code is executed? I assume, that status code should be sent before any response text, with other http-headers. Is it possible, that you missed a line-break at start of some file, or there is a notice missed? I would also try changing response status code with another parent controller. And, at last, debugging must show, when status code is changed to 200 in response object.

Comment: Actually, first thing i would do, is find all "setStatusCode()" usages in project and Zend, set a debug-break on everyone, and run debug. :)

Comment: What is the name of your controller method? Maybe it correlates with some Zend's magical calls?

Comment: @Xardas Controller method name is `get()`, which is inherited from `AbstractRESTfulController`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45374/discussion-between-geek-and-xardas)

Answer (score 8):

I've just tested this with a simple example project at https://github.com/akrabat/zf2-api-response-code

In a controller that extends `AbstractRestfulController`, you can certainly use

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
    public function create($data)
    {
        $this->response->setStatusCode(401);
        return new JsonModel(array("message" => "Please authenticate!"));
    }
}
```

Testing via curl, I get this:

```
$ curl -v -X POST http://zf2-api-example.localhost/
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f880b003a00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f880b003a00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to zf2-api-example.localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to zf2-api-example.localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: zf2-api-example.localhost
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2014 10:02:47 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 34
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
<
* Connection #0 to host zf2-api-example.localhost left intact
{"message":"Please authenticate!"}
```

As you can see, the response code set is 401. If you're not getting this with your application, please check my example on github and see if that one works with your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$statusCode = 401;
$response = $this->response;
$response->setStatusCode($statusCode);
$response->setContent(new JsonModel(array("error message" => "error description")));
return $response;
```

If this does not work, there might be an `onDispatch` event handler which overwrites the status code again. Check your `Module.php`'s.

Comment: I use the same code. I don't have `onDispatch` event handler in `Module.php` file. I have added its code to my question. I don't know why, but it worked yesterday for some times and then after some point it gives 200 only.

Comment: Is it related to the thing that `response` is object of class `\Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response` or `\Zend\Http\Response`? Doing `var_dump($this->response)` says that it is `\Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response` object.

Comment: No, I don't think so. You sure `setStatusCode` never gets called after your setting it to 401?

Comment: Actually I return the response just after setting the status code. So I can say that there is not code overriding status code value. I am new to zend so if there is something happening behind the screen then I have very less idea about it.